# Using JavaScript to manipulate HTML input (checkbox) elements via type instead of name

Tags: javascript, html

I am implementing an HTML form with some checkbox input elements, and I want to have a Select All or DeSelect All button. However, *I do not want to rely on the name* of the input element (like [this example](http://www.plus2net.com/javascript_tutorial/checkbox-checkall.php)) but rather the **type** because I have multiple checkbox groups with different names. Is there a way to check and uncheck all checkbox input elements within a form with JavaScript by relying on the type instead of the name?

Edit: We rely on YUI libraries, so I have access YUI if that provides a solution.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

This should do it:

```
<script>
function checkUncheck(form, setTo) {
    var c = document.getElementById(form).getElementsByTagName('input');
    for (var i = 0; i < c.length; i++) {
        if (c[i].type == 'checkbox') {
            c[i].checked = setTo;
        }
    }
}
</script>

<form id='myForm'>
<input type='checkbox' name='test' value='1'><br>
<input type='checkbox' name='test' value='1'><br>
<input type='checkbox' name='test' value='1'><br>
<input type='checkbox' name='test' value='1'><br>
<input type='checkbox' name='test' value='1'><br>
<input type='button' onclick="checkUncheck('myForm', true);" value='Check'>
<input type='button' onclick="checkUncheck('myForm', false);" value='Uncheck'>
</form>
```

Comment: It seems a bit risky to assume that what you want is to flip the state of each checkbox. On the other hand, the code does provide a useful starting point for solving the OP's problem.

Comment: I would suggest having a second attribute of wether to check/uncheck, because your method will simply toggle all, not check/uncheck all.

Comment: Is reasonable to only fetch the inputs, therefor leaving out all selects or textareas. Like in this example.

Answer (score 1):

iterate through the form.elements collection and check .type == "checkbox".

```
var button = getSelectAllButtonInFormSomeHow();
/*all formelements have a reference to the form. And the form has an elements-collection.*/
var elements = button.form.elements;

for(var i = 0; i < elements.length;i++) {
    var input = elements[i];
    if (input.tagName == "input" && input.type == "checkbox") input.checked = true;
}
```

Comment: I don't really understand why the formatting doesn't work. It looks okay in the preview...

Answer (score 1):

```
function findCheckBoxes(el, check) {
        for(var i=0;el.childNodes[i];i++)
        {
            var child = el.childNodes[i];
            if (child.type=="checkbox")
            {
                child.checked = check;
            }
            if (child.childNodes.length > 0)
                this.findCheckBoxes(child, check);
        }
    }
```

Comment: This would assume that the form only have inputs as childelements, which seldom is the case. And you don't need recursive functions for this.

Answer (score 1):

Every input element has an attribute, type, which for checkboxes is "checkbox" so you could try something like this:

```
for (var i = 0; i < document.myForm.elements.length; i++) {
    if (document.myForm.elements[i].type == "checkbox") {
        document.myForm.elements[i].checked = true;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If jQuery is an option you can do this rather easily.

See the documentation on [jQuery selectors](http://docs.jquery.com/API/1.1.2/DOM/Traversing/Selectors#Using_CSS_and_XPath_Together). (The last example in the section shows how to do it with radio buttons but just replace that with check boxes.)

Comment: Thanks SR. Unfortunately, jQuery is not an option, but YUI is. I should probably mention that in the question.

Answer (score 0):

Is assigning a class to all required checkbox elements an option? If yes, then this is how I would do it (assuming "class_name" is the name of the css class present in all checkbox elements in question):

```
function selectCheckBoxes(bChecked) {
   var aCheckBoxes = YAHOO.util.Dom.getElementsByClassName('class_name', 'input');
   for (var i = 0; i < aCheckBoxes.length; i++) {
      aCheckBoxes[i].checked = bChecked;
   }
}
```

If you want to stay away from classes, but can get parent element by ID (or any other method, I will use ID in the example, though), than you can do this:

```
function selectCheckBoxes(bChecked) {
   var oParent = document.getElementById('parentsID');
   var aElements = oParent.getElementsByTagName('input');
   for (var i = 0; i < aElements.length; i++) {
      if (aElements[i].type == 'checkbox') {
         aElements[i].checked = bChecked;
      }
   }
}
```

I would stick to the "class" method, however.

Answer (score -3):

```
<html>
<head>
<script>
function selectCheckBox()
{   
     if(document.getElementById('id11').checked==true)
     {
        document.frm.id2.checked=true
        document.frm.id3.checked=true
        document.frm.id4.checked=true
     }
     if(document.getElementById('id11').checked==false)
     {
        document.frm.id2.checked=false
        document.frm.id3.checked=false
        document.frm.id4.checked=false
     }
}
function selectCheckBox1()
{
     if(document.getElementById('id12').checked==false)
     {
        document.frm.id1.checked=false
     }  
}
function selectCheckBox2()
{
     if(document.getElementById('id13').checked==false)
     {
        document.frm.id1.checked=false
     }  
}
function selectCheckBox3()
{
     if(document.getElementById('id14').checked==false)
     {
        document.frm.id1.checked=false
     }  
}
</script>

</head>
<body>
<form name="frm">
All   :<input type="checkbox" id="id11" name="id1" value="1" onClick="selectCheckBox()"><br>
A.    :<input type="checkbox" id="id12" name="id2" value="2" onClick="selectCheckBox1()"><br>
B.    :<input type="checkbox" id="id13" name="id3" value="3" onClick="selectCheckBox2()"><br>
C.    :<input type="checkbox" id="id14" name="id4" value="4" onClick="selectCheckBox3()"><br>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: If relying on the names is bad, relying on the IDs is even worse.  Add to that, the way you're doing this means having a function for each checkbox.  This is ugly in the extreme, especially if you end up having like 100 checkboxes.