# Check all check boxes in MVC view

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Using JavaScript to manipulate HTML input (checkbox) elements via type instead of name.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/463535/using-javascript-to-manipulate-html-input-checkbox-elements-via-type-instead-of)

Why does this not work ? Please help. This is code to check all checkboxes on a MVC view.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function SetAllCheckBoxes(doc) {
        var c = new Array();
        c = doc.getElementsByTagName('input');
        for (var i = 0; i < c.length; i++) {
            if (c[i].type == 'checkbox') {
                c[i].checked = true;
            }
        }
    }
</script>
<input type="checkbox" name="Test" onclick="SetAllCheckBoxes('PartialViewName')"/>
```

Answer (score 7):

You're passing `'PartialViewName'` as a string when your function seems to use it as a `document` object.

Try this js:

```
function SetAllCheckBoxes(obj) {
    var c = new Array();
    c = document.getElementsByTagName('input');
    for (var i = 0; i < c.length; i++) {
        if (c[i].type == 'checkbox') {
            c[i].checked = obj.checked;
        }
    }
}
```

And wire up your toggler checkbox like this:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="Test" onclick="SetAllCheckBoxes(this)"/>
```

Working Example: http://jsfiddle.net/hunter/fA2w5/

---

With jQuery it is extremely simple:

```
<input type="checkbox" id="Test" name="Test" />

$("#Test").click(function(){
    $("input:checkbox:not(#Test)").attr("checked", $(this).is(":checked"));
});
```

Working Example: http://jsfiddle.net/hunter/fA2w5/3/

Comment: +1 for answering the question

Comment: Sorry this also doesnot work .. am I still passing the partial view name in the onclick event? <input type="checkbox" name="Test" onclick="SetAllCheckBoxes('PartialViewName')"/>

Comment: check out my updates, should work with js or jQuery. See both of my examples

Answer (score 4):

Try to use [jquery selector](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/), if you can:

```
$("input:checkbox").attr("checked","checked");
```

Also, you should use the `document`, not `doc` in your code:

```
 document.getElementsByTagName('input');
```

Comment: Where exactly does this line of code go?

Comment: @ZVenue This line selects all the input having their type equal to input:checkbox, and after that add the `checked` attribute to all of them.